# Analytic Function on the Closed Unit Disc with No Continuation

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I believe G.H. Hardy proved the existence of a Maclaurin series which was analytic on the unit disc and converged on the entire boundary of the unit disc (and was continuous on the closed disc), but which had no analytic continuation beyond the closed disc. Does anyone know of such a function? I cannot find the paper, so does anyone know of it?

Comment: take $\sum z^{2^n}/2^{n}$ which clearly works

Comment: @Conrad It's clear that the radius of convergence is $1$ and that the series converges on the entire boundary of the unit disc, but why is it clear that this function has no analytic continuation beyond the unit disc?

Comment: If it has analytic continuation at a point, then it has analytic continuation on a small neighborhood so the derivative $f'$ does also, hence $zf'$ does too; but  $zf'= \sum z^{2^n}$ which has the unit circle as natural boundary since it goes to infinity at any root of unity of order a power of two and those are dense (also all follows from the famous gap theorems but here it's easy to show stuff directly as above); note that by tweaking the above one can arrange that the function is infinitely real differentiable on the unit circle not only continuous and still with natural boundary there

Comment: @Conrad Feel free to post that as an answer, it's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!